# What is a good algo for glsl lowp random number generation (for use in graphics)?

Tags: random, glsl

I need a random number generator to create some graphical static. I'm not looking for noise algorithms- I just want white noise. All I need for this is a random number generator in glsl. Specifically, I'll be using it to create a random lightness offset per-fragment, over time.

Requirements:

- generates number between 0.0 and 1.0 (don't care if inclusive/exclusive)
- This needn't be *that* random. This won't be used for any security purposes, it just needs to be "random" to the naked eye.
- It needs to be computable with **lowp** floats only! (for use on mobile)
- Only has fragment_x, fragment_y, and time_mod_ten_pi as inputs (time_mod_ten_pi is exactly what it sounds like; the time (in seconds) since the game began, mod (10*3.1415) passed in as a float to allow for easy, continuous oscillations without worrying about precision issues. and 30 seconds is waaay more than enough time that a human won't notice repeating noise)
- when displayed on a fragment_x * fragment_y grid, I don't want any visible patterns (statically, or in motion)
- the simpler/faster, the better!

want to reiterate here- ***needs to function with only lowp floats***. that one-liner going around the internet (fract(sin(dot(...)))) does **not** fulfill this condition! (at least, I assume the issue is with the lowp floats... could be really feeble sin implementation as well... so if you can avoid sin of high numbers too? bonus?)

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I've been able to come up with, but I'm still not 100% satisfied (you can still see a small kaleidoscope-like effect if you look hard enough...

```
float rand(float frag_x, float frag_y, float t)
{
  float r = t*7.924;
  return fract(sin(frag_y+frag_x)*r+sin(frag_y-frag_x)*r*.7);
}
```

(the 7.924 and the .7 is me mashing on the keyboard- nothing more)

Answer (score 1):

GLSL ES 1.0 (the version of GLSL used in OpenGL ES 2.0 and WebGL 1.0) requires at least support for `mediump` precision numbers in fragment shaders and other shaders. For your purposes, `mediump` numbers cover at least all integers in the range (-1024, 1024) (so 10 bits in precision besides the sign bit), and `mediump` floating-point numbers cover all multiples of 1/1024 in the range [0, 1]. These ranges are quite small, however. (For further information on `mediump` number requirements, see sec. 4.5, "Precision and Precision Qualifiers", of the GLSL ES 1.0 specification).

Your use of the term "lowp floats" is rather vague, though, so for the purposes of this question, I assume you use "lowp floats" to mean floating-point numbers meeting the minimum requirements for `mediump` numbers in GLSL ES 1.0, which have to be available in all implementations of GLSL ES 1.0. (Note that GLSL ES 1.0's `lowp` numbers can have a range as low as (-2, 2) and a precision as low as 8 bits, making them much less suitable for your purposes.)

Thus, for "lowp floats" as just defined, you should find a pseudorandom number generator (or hash function) that can be calculated:

- With 5-bit integers only. The function can perform two calls of the generator (one for the first 5 bits, another for the last 5 bits), combine the results, then divide by 1024.0.
- With 10-bit integers only. The function can thus perform one call of the generator, then divide the generated number by 1024.0.

This approach will generate a pseudorandom number in the interval [0, 1) that's a multiple of 1/1024.

---

For GLSL, a viable alternative may be to sample from a texture made up of uniformly distributed pseudorandom numbers. See also "[Free blue noise textures](http://momentsingraphics.de/?p=127)" for a similar approach involving sampling blue noise textures. Obviously, since "lowp floats" have a precision as low as 10 bits, the texture should not be more than 1024 pixels wide or 1024 pixels high.