# What is the fractional precision of highp clip space coordinates in WebGL and WebGL2?

Tags: html5-canvas, webgl, precision, webgl2

[In MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/WebGL_best_practices#essl300_minimum_requirements_webgl_2) it says that:

- In WebGL1, the precision of `highp` is `2^-16`, which is `0.00001525878`.
  In other words, I only have the "resolution" of 5 digits after the decimal point, right?
- In WebGL2, the precision of `highp` is `2^-24`, which is `0.00000005960`.
  In other words, I only have the "resolution" of 7 digits after the decimal point, right?

In the same time, in JavaScript, the max safe integer is 9007199254740991, which is 16 digits. Which is at least 9 orders of magnitude bigger number of digits than in both WebGL1 and WebGL2 floats.

I understand it as if the "resolution" of coordinates in JavaScript integers are 9 orders of magnitude higher than the resolution of the clip space coordinates.

Is my understanding correct?

If so, what is the reasoning behind converting from a 16-digits worth of coordinate resolution to vertex shader's -1...1 range with up to 7 digits worth of coordinate resolution, and, most importantly, then converting back to the canvas viewport where we, again, have a better "resolution" because the coordinates are in integer numbers? Won't we lose precision as we go form integer numbers to deciman numbers between -1...1 in the clip space, and then back again to he canvas space with integer numbers, e.g. ~0...18k points (with device ratio of 3 and canvas size of 6k css pixels).

Comment: The precision of `highp` (and `mediump` and `lowp`) is governed by GLSL ES 1.0 or 3.0, rather than WebGL 1.0 and 2.0 itself.  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360048/what-is-a-good-algo-for-glsl-lowp-random-number-generation-for-use-in-graphics/56217458#56217458

Comment: Yes, but it does not answer my question in any way.

Comment: Yes, the link I gave is not intended to answer this question, but rather is one example of how precision specifiers like `highp` are governed less by WebGL than by GLSL.